# Carving a struct memory layout "in stone"

Tags: c++, struct, memory-alignment

Maybe this topic has been beaten to death but I can't find any "conclusive" answers. Anyway, I need to specify a plain old data only struct in C++17 that will be read/written to/from an external memory as a "raw chunk of bytes". This external memory content must specify it's memory layout "forever", regardless of any changing compiler settings, new compiler brands or versions, today and decades from now.

I am currently using the C++ **alignas **keyword and fixed width data types for every struct member but is this really the best approach? Any suggestions and gotchas would be greately appreciated.

FYI, this is an embedded project on an STM32H7xx MCU using ST CubeIDE.

Comment: Yes, if you want full control you need to use fixed width types and specify the alignment you want.

Comment: A more portable option would be to *serialize* your data into/from the memory block as needed.  No need to manually align a struct's members, and you would be able to use non-POD types, like `std::string`.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a way too broad portability. Do you at least assume a fixed ABI and/or architecture in this picture? Otherwise what is preventing e.g. `CHAR_BIT` from being `16` in the future, so that even counting raw bytes won't be correct anymore, or endianess being different, etc?

Comment: Fixed width and alignment isn't enough, you also need to specify endianness.

Comment: I'd also add `static_assert(sizeof(MyStruct) == 42)` somewhere near your structure definition.

Comment: It is generally preferable to use some text format like json or xml to avoid that problem among others. As an added benefit, you can more easily inspect the file in case of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I only have 512 bytes storage space available so any "advanced" method would probably add too much overhead. I agree, endianness could be an issue but if it is documented, any future change could handle it in code.

Answer (score 1):

There are many pitfalls of using fixed width data.

Being limited to 512 bytes is tricky. If you feel you can represent the data as reasonably portable data (32 or 64 bit int, float, double), then I'd use base64 encoding of your information in a sequence you choose and compress using zstd (best) or gzip (easy).

This should get you [about 486 bytes](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/01/30/what-is-the-space-overhead-of-base64-encoding/) of your data store in the 512 byte location and weather most compiler changes and other issues.

Comment: Yes. not having to rely on predictable and strict "bit patterns" (memory layout) is certainly advantageous but I think for this application it is probably a bit overkill. The structure format will always be available for future developers in the code if making significant changes such as processor architectures etc. For now I just want to make sure that, for example, a simple default data alignment setting change in the project doesn't break the code.